# Passing string variable to Sharepoint command without desired outcome

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, powershell-3.0

I have a number of fields that I am using to build a string for an extraction of values from a SharePoint 2013 list.

I use this to build the string.

```
foreach($Column in $StringColumns){
$Fields=$Fields+"`""+$Column+"`""
if($Loop -ne $ColumnCount){
$Fields=$Fields+","
$Loop++}
}
```

I take the built `$Fields` [string] variable and pass it to this command.

```
$SPList.getitems($queryfromsource)[$ItemNumber][$Fields]
```

The result is that I receive no output from the command.  What makes it odd is that I can confirm that `$Fields` has the appropriate string in it for that command.  I have done so by calling it in the console and then copying the output into the SharePoint command directly.  When I do that, I receive the output I am looking for.

This seems like it should be incredibly simple but it is driving me insane.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that on the ISE Console the resultant value of `$Fields` is quite long and wraps to 5 lines.  If I put the command into the console it works when I remove the line breaks.  Is this perhaps an interaction with ISE?

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work?

```
foreach ($Column in $StringColumns)
{
    $Fields+= "`"$($Column)`""
    if ($Loop -ne $ColumnCount)
    {
        $Fields+= ","
        $Loop++
        # Only use Write-Host for debugging
        Write-Host "Column $Loop of $ColumnCount" 
    }
}
```

Do you initialize $Loop somewhere, might try having it print the loop number you're on?

Comment: I do initialize `$Loop` previous to this block, I just didn't include it.  One thing I may have failed to specify is that the SharePoint command that the variable `$Fields` is being passed to needs to be in a format like `"Field1","Field2",...`

Comment: The loop I listed should keep that format. The Write-Host is just a way to visualize that the loop actually is running. ($Fields += $Column) == ($Fields = $Fields + $Column)

Comment: I understand the shorthand portion and it is more correct to use that method.  I'm just saying that I used the escape characters so that the output was `"Field1","Field2",...` instead of `Field1,Field2,...` which is what your version returns.

Comment: Ahh, my bad, was thinking that those quotes would carry over, I'll make a small edit that should work

Answer (score 0):

You probably should learn a bit about string building techniques in PowerShell. That convoluted construct you have there is not just too much work to create, it's also difficult to debug, as your example proves perfectly. You need to initialize `$Loop` to 1, not 0 (I assume that's what you are doing, please always post the complete code), or put the `$Loop++` at the beginning of the loop, otherwise the string has a comma at the end. You also need to initialize the `$Fields` variable to an empty string.

Have you checked the string output of your script by printing the actual variable? If you check it in the console, you might have already initialized some variable which you forgot to do in the script.

A much easier way to build the string:

```
$columns = 'Title', 'Created', 'Description'

$string = "`"$($columns -join '","')`""
```

Comment: I will work on learning a bit.  Your method is certainly more elegant, thank you for making me aware that join is available for string building.  The output of my construct is identical to yours and provides an equally failing result.  The loop is initialized as you stated.